# What is '@' used for in c++

Tags: c++, gsoap

I'm reading gSOAP documentation from here:
https://www.genivia.com/dev.html#services

There is a sample of generated code:

```
#import "gsoap/import/stlvector.h" // import std::vector XML data binding

//gsoap ns schema namespace: HR
class ns__employee {
  public:
   @std::string                name    1;        // required name attribute
   @int                        ID      0 = 9999; // optional ID attribute, defaults to 9999
    std::vector<ns__employee*> manages 0:12;     // up to 12 <manages> elements
};
```

This looks like c++ but what is it?
`@std::string name 1;` , `@int                        ID      0 = 9999;`, `std::vector<ns__employee*> manages 0:12;` - this looks like bitfields.

Comment: This seems to be their own markup. They probably have a tool that extracts the markup data and removes the markup info before sending it to the compiler.

Comment: The gSOAP documentation says "Note that annotations such as @ are used to distinguish attributes from elements. These annotations are gSOAP-specific and are handled by the soapcpp2 tool that reads this generated interface file and generates the XML data binding implementation with serializers for the data types declared in the interface file."

Comment: `name 1` does not look like bitfield, but syntax errror. Looks like some data that will be processed into c++

Comment: This is not standard C++. It's either a compiler specific extension, a language dialect or some syntax meant to be processed by a tool before being passed to an actual C++ compiler.